# how to group results

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am a c# programmer but I have never needed to use XSLT. I do now and I am stuck

Given some xmls I need to use XSLT to produce an html output.Googling a bit I did manage to put something together that worked till my boss told me that "**Tables and columns must be build dynamically into the xslt document**.I was hardcoding the columns names.
All columns header must be horizontally.

[image: Sample output]

Any help writing the xslt?The one I did was useless as it hardcoded the columns

**EDITED**

```
<Generated>
  <Employees>
    <Employee name="Joe Bloggs">
      <Sales>
        <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="2323" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="Field1sale" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="field2Sale" />
       </Sales>
     </Employee>
      <Employee name="Mark Bloggs">
      <Sales>
        <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="334" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="Field1sale" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="field2Sale" />
       </Sales>
     </Employee>
  </Employees>
  <Products>
    <Product name="Rice">
      <Sales>
        <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="334" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="Field1sale" />
        <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="field2Sale" />
       </Sales>
     </Product>
      <Product name="Wine">
          <Sales>
            <Sale key="Sale-Id" value="32" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field1" value="Field1sale" />
            <Sale key="Sale-Field2" value="field2Sale" />
           </Sales>
     </Product>
  </Products>
</Generated>
```

I KNOW IT'S WRONG BUT LEARNING ABOUT XSLT

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
          <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)[1]/Sales/Sale[@key != 'Sale-Id']">
              <xsl:for-each select="Generated/Employees/Employee">
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:for-each select="./Sales/Sale[@key != 'Sale-Id']">
              </xsl:for-each>
              <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Side note: It's always better to include your code as text rather than image, because I doubt that someone who wish to test your case will bother to re-type your code from picture manually. And it's better for you to actually show your attempt and specify where it is failed, because right now your question sounds like "write code for me, please", but StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev yes you are right ,but difficult when you don t actually know anything about xslt.I will  put my attempt as well

Comment: Either use XSL2.0, which contains a group-by node, or implement the [muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Comment: @developer9969 Pardon my being blunt, but if you "*don't actually know anything about xslt*", then you shouldn't be asking on Stack Overflow, because you won't be able to understand the answers. Do at least a basic tutorial first, e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have read about xslt and done and made it work producing a what I wanted but was not dynamic I was hardcoding the columns.I can look up and take it from there I am not going to put something in production I dont fully understand but I need pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming your columns `Sale-Field1` etc are the same for all `Employees` and can be taken from first employee record (it it's not true - then task is significantly harder) - basically all you need is `<xsl:for-each>` and `<xsl:value-of>`.

Second requirement - you should basically understand `xpath` queries, as it is used to retrieve data from xml.

So, for creating your header you can use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="(Generated/Employees/Employee)[1]/Sales/Sale[@key != 'Sale-Id']">
```

This will iterate over `Sale` nodes of first `Employee` node having attribute `key` not equal to `Sale-Id` (as you don't need this in your table). On that iteration you can get attribute `value` as `<xsl:value-of select="@key" />`

That's all with header, let go to rows. You can iterate over employees the same way as before:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Generated/Employees/Employee">
```

And now after you get name of employee as `<xsl:value-of select="@name" />`, you need one more nested loop - over Sales:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Sales/Sale[@key != 'Sale-Id']">
```

Note here we are using relative xpath started with `./`. And finally, in that loop you can get your values as `<xsl:value-of select="@value" />`

And yes - I see no any "grouping" in your desired table output - so it's unclear why it was mentioned in title.

Comment: thanks for your time in replying I have added the xslt but it's not producing results,I know its wrong but not sure.Could you have a look.

Comment: @developer9969 aside from logic of loops in your code (which looks totally incorrect) - you are not generating any html markdown (such as `<html>`, `<body>`, `<table>` and so on), and the only output in your code is `<xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>` which will output nothing because xml is **case sensitive**, and attributes in your sample xml is `value` not `Value`.

Comment: I am a very experienced c# developer but never played with xslt done lot of linq to xml etc... Truly I should learn the basic xslt and do it,reality is I have not got the time to learn xslt since i have a crazy deadline,I am stuck I know but there you go.In 10 years of dev I was never asked to do xslt. I would have got away with it if I could have hardcoded the columns I had a simple xslt that worked

Answer (score 3):

For the header row, create a cell for each field of the **first** record, using the @key value. For the body, create a row for each record, then a cell for each field, this time using the @value value.

This is assuming each record has exactly the same fields list. Use a *predicate* in order to exclude some fields from the list - such as Sale-Id in your example.

I don't see what this has to do with grouping.

Comment: what should I google to find a small tutorial todo what you are saying